# Flutter text does not appear completely

Tags: google-chrome, flutter, web, dart

My flutter web project does not show text completely in android chrome.

It should be 'المميزات' but it is cut from below so the dots and rest of 'ز' are not appearing.

It works on pc and mobile Mozilla Firefox -except one character-

Note: it was working at the beginning of the project.

I don't have enough repetition to post an image.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a white space at the end of the word or sentence for a workaround. I believe this will be fixed in the next update.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Web do have a number of issues with text rendering on web. But I'm not sure if there is an issue that your case fit into. If not, perhaps report it on github.

Some of the issues:

- [Text after hypen does not render](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65099)
- [Missing text in standalone mode](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64904)
- [Text is clipped in Firefox](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61614)

All web issues on github:

- [Flutter web issues on github](http://is:open%20label:platform-web)

**edit:** As pointed out in a comment, be sure to include code to reproduce your issue especially if you decide to report it on github.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it, by building my web build with the Canvas renderer with this command: `flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit`.

CanvasKid renderer defintion:

> This renderer is fully consistent with Flutter mobile and desktop, has
> faster performance with higher widget density, but adds about 2MB in
> download size.

More infos about this renderer on https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/renderers